# How do I limit filesystem disk usage per user?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, files, disk-space-utilization

I have an ubuntu server. With a ext3 formatted filesystem. How can I limit a certain user to only be able to use X MB of disk space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install quota
```

[This link](http://computingtech.blogspot.com/2008/09/ubuntu-linux-disk-quotas.html) or [this link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-setup-disk-quotas-in-ubuntu.html) have nice tutorials on how to set up quota.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for one-off quota needs that does not depend on kernel quota support is to create a disk image and use a loopback mount to access it. [This link](http://www.schmut.com/cheat-sheets/linux-directory-quota) shows how to do it.